Getting marker from ClusterRenderer return null for clustered marker
Am trying to select and unselect marker using cluster data through cluster renderer. Am getting null when getting marker for clustered marker.
private fun setMarkerIcon(item: ClusterData) {
    val icon = markerIconGenerator.makeIcon()
    val bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)
    clusterRenderer?.getMarker(item)?.setIcon(bitmapDescriptor) //getting null here
}

I have tried with cluster manager markerCollection and clusterMarkerCollection. Same it return null for clustered marker.
clusterManager.clusterMarkerCollection.markers.find { it.snippet == item.snippet }
            ?.let { marker ->
                ////
            } ?: run { ////getting here }


clusterManager.clusterMarkerCollection?.markers?.find {  it.snippet == item.snippet }?.let {
        ////
    } ?: run { ////getting here }

DefaultClusterRenderer
class AppClusterRenderer(
private val context: Context,
map: GoogleMap,
clusterManager: ClusterManager<ClusterData>) : 
DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterData>(context, map, clusterManager) {


private val clusterIconGenerator = IconGenerator(context)

private val markerIconGenerator = IconGenerator(context)

init {
    clusterIconGenerator.setContentView(clusterBinder.root)
    clusterIconGenerator.setBackground(null)
    markerIconGenerator.setContentView(markerBinder.root)
    markerIconGenerator.setBackground(null)
}

override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: ClusterData, markerOptions: MarkerOptions) {
    markerOptions.icon(getMarkerItemView(item))
    //getMarkerItemView set needed data and return bitmap
}

private fun getMarkerItemView(item: ClusterData): BitmapDescriptor {
    val icon = markerIconGenerator.makeIcon()
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)
}

private fun getClusterItemView(size: Int): BitmapDescriptor {
    clusterBinder.tvCount.text = size.toString()
    val icon = clusterIconGenerator.makeIcon()
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)
}


override fun onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem: ClusterData, marker: Marker) {
    super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker)
}

override fun getDescriptorForCluster(cluster: Cluster<ClusterData>): BitmapDescriptor {
    return getClusterItemView(cluster.size)
}

override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<ClusterData>): Boolean {
    return cluster.size >= 2
}

}

Thank you for the support.
